# How to output date in javascript in ISO 8601 without milliseconds and with Z

Tags: javascript, date, iso8601

Here is a standard way to serialise date as ISO 8601 string in JavaScript:

```js
var now = new Date();
console.log( now.toISOString() );
// outputs '2015-12-02T21:45:22.279Z'
```

I need just the same output, but without milliseconds. How can I output `2015-12-02T21:45:22Z` ?

Comment: `(new Date).toISOString().replace(/\.\d+/, "")`.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Simple way:

```js
console.log( new Date().toISOString().split('.')[0]+"Z" );
```

Comment: BTW, this also works for getting just the date with a slight modification: `new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]`

Comment: Please use `(new Date)` instead of the ugly `new Date()`.

Answer (score 40):

Use slice to remove the undesired part

```
var now = new Date();
alert( now.toISOString().slice(0,-5)+"Z");
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it's 10x faster than the solutions using split() and 3x faster than the regex solution. The only (unlisted) solution of equal speed is now.toISOString().substr(0,19) + "Z".  And extra speed is helpful when using this with large data sets. Up voted.

Comment: @Roberto If I was looking for speed, I would use `console.log( now.substring(0, now.indexOf('.'))+"Z");` since toISOString() is 24 or 27 characters long. (`now = new Date().toISOString();` in my example)

Comment: For those who are debating whether to `.slice(0,-5)` vs. `.substring(0,19)`, even at 0 milliseconds, ".000Z" will be returned.

Answer (score 21):

This is the solution:

```
var now = new Date(); 
var str = now.toISOString();
var res = str.replace(/\.[0-9]{3}/, '');
alert(res);
```

Finds the . (dot) and removes 3 characters.

http://jsfiddle.net/boglab/wzudeyxL/7/

Comment: Surprised me that this is actually faster than the solutions using split.  And it also avoids having to add back the Z.  Up voted, though the slice and substr solutions are slightly better.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a combination of [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to remove the milliseconds from an [ISO 8601](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) string:

```js
let date = new Date().toISOString().split('.').shift() + 'Z';

console.log(date);
```

Comment: I think `shift()` might be overkill especially if you're just trying to get the first value in the array. It's just extra overhead.

Answer (score 6):

It is similar to @STORM's answer:

```js
const date = new Date();

console.log(date.toISOString());
console.log(date.toISOString().replace(/[.]\d+/, ''));
```

Comment: `/\.\d+/` is also possible.

Comment: the `\.` can be difficult to read sometimes, so I have changed into using `[.]`

Answer (score 2):

or probably overwrite it with this? (this is a modified polyfill from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString#Polyfill))

```
function pad(number) {
  if (number < 10) {
    return '0' + number;
  }
  return number;
}

Date.prototype.toISOStringShort = function() {
  return this.getUTCFullYear() +
    '-' + pad(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) +
    '-' + pad(this.getUTCDate()) +
    'T' + pad(this.getUTCHours()) +
    ':' + pad(this.getUTCMinutes()) +
    ':' + pad(this.getUTCSeconds()) +
    'Z';
};
```

Comment: Not a bad idea but the person probably down voted because of the dangers of overwriting the prototype! Extend it instead and call your method something like `Date.prototype.toISOStringSansMilliseconds` or some such

Comment: Please never change builtin methods.