# How to convert a date from one type to another typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, date-fns

React with Typescript:

I have a date picker(mui v5) that requires date value to be in format "yyyy-MM-dd".
However the api return a type Date on the format "2022-01-12T00:00:00.000+00:00"

Attention: There are **many answers** to create a string in that format but I need a **Date** without this it won't work with typescrit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to output date in javascript in ISO 8601 without milliseconds and with Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053715/how-to-output-date-in-javascript-in-iso-8601-without-milliseconds-and-with-z)

Comment: no, doing this I have a string not a date

Comment: can't you just use `new Date("2022-01-12T00:00:00.000+00:00")`?
Then you have the actual Date obj

Comment: It returns a Date in other format Tue Dec 28 2021 21:00:00 GMT-0300

Comment: I am still not sure what your problem is. I've looked up the MUI v5 Date Picker and it takes a `Date` object. If you pass your string `"2022-01-12T00:00:00.000+00:00"` to `Date()` and pass that date to the DatePicker component it will show up correctly on the webpage? See this [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/k5llth?file=/demo.tsx) from the MUI docs. Only thing you need to change is pass in `"2022-01-12T00:00:00.000+00:00"` into the `Date()` constructor for the initial date value.

Comment: interesting, in my case only displayed the date if value was in the shape 'yyyy-mm-dd', I changed the API and now it's solved

Answer (score 0):

There are basically to ways to do this.

#### String manipulation

Just use the ISO 8601 string you already have and manipulate it using `split()` or `substring()` so that you only have the relevant portion of the string. Use this when you don't need to do any calculation/ further processing with the date.

#### toLocaleDateString()

Parse the string first by passing it to the `Date()` constructor then format it using `toLocaleDateString()` and the locale `en-CA` to yield the result you need. The advantage of this approach is that you could do some processing that involves the date before eventually converting it to string.

```js
const strManipulationSplit = "2022-01-12T00:00:00.000+00:00".split("T")[0];
const strManipulationSubstring = "2022-01-12T00:00:00.000+00:00".substring(0, 10);
const usingDate = new Date("2022-01-12T00:00:00.000+00:00").toLocaleDateString('en-CA');

console.log(strManipulationSplit);
console.log(strManipulationSubstring);
console.log(usingDate);
```

Comment: usingDate is a string, in the right format, but not a date, this results in a typescript error when I try to set as the value to pass to my date picker

Comment: If you need a `Date` object just don't use `toLocaleString()` and you will have a `Date`.

Comment: Because it return in another format Tue Dec 28 2021 21:00:00 GMT-0300, not yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: What do you mean with it returns `Tue Dec 28 2021 21:00:00 GMT-0300`? Your result is in timezone `GMT-3` (which probably is your locale) and the string is assumed to be `UTC` (= `GMT-0`) hence the 3 hour difference in time. *00:00:00* in `UTC` and *21:00:00* in `GMT-3`. What I don't get why your so many days off? That doesn't add up for me. Which function do you call to get this result? `toString()`?

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion is that it can't be solved through React or JS

If I do:

const strManipulationSplit = "2022-01-12T00:00:00.000+00:00".split("T")[0];
const strManipulationSubstring = "2022-01-12T00:00:00.000+00:00".substring(0, 10);
const usingDate = new Date("2022-01-12T00:00:00.000+00:00");

the return will be like: "Tue Dec 28 2021 21:00:00 GMT-0300" not "yyyy-MM-dd"

So I changed the API to return the format "yyyy-MM-dd"